# In Vue cli, How to use custom mode and build like in production mode?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm building a Vue app and want to override some env variables while building in one build case, so I created a custom `mode` and sat a command in `package.json` like:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode myMode --modern
```

And put the env vars I want in the file specified for this mode:

```
// file name: .env.myMode
VUE_APP_MY_VAR=123
```

Now how can I build using the same build steps in `production` mode but within my custom mode?
Because when I build using the previous command it doesn't mangle or compress the js files for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `NODE_ENV=production` into `.env.myMode`

[Docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)

> Then NODE_ENV will determine the primary mode your app is running in - development, production or test - and consequently, what kind of webpack config will be created.